# build doxygen on windows, xapian.lib and how to run flex

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit, doxygen

I've hit a catch 22 situation, I've hit a bug in the current release version of doxygen which has stopped me in my tracks. Luckily it looks like the bug is fixed by a patch in the git.

So, here's where my problems begin, I need to build doxygen for windows from the latest git. Ouch, the help on this is really thin on the ground.

Anyway, I've got the sources and all the dependencies to build the core (doxygen.exe). On the latest release sources this works fine. But the git sources are giving me some trouble, here's an example:

1>..\src\vhdlscanner.l(766) : error C2065: 'vhdlscannerYY_flex_debug' : undeclared identifier

So, I'm guessing I need to run some source file prepping commands using flex and bison. Is there a handy script I can use or can someone give me some commands.

I kinda gave up trying to build the whole doxygen project as it looks like it needs xapian... which I went and built (core only) and it doesn't seem to produce a xapian.lib. So I'm hosed there, any tips for this would be a nice bonus.

Some version stuff that might be important, but I doubt it:

Visual Studio C++ Express 2008 (2005 & 2013 also available if they're better for this)
bison 2.4.1
flex 2.5.4
QT 4.8.5
xapian (core) 1.2.8 & 1.0.23

Cheers,
Craig.

Comment: So a dirty hack was to go through the source files and delete any lines which start "printlex(yy_flex_debug,". 

Is there a script for this?
The bug that stopped me is still present in the latest sources:
Looks like doxygen is failing to generate a correct section code for some of my package files (should be CLASS_SEC, I'm getting VARIABLE_SEC), I'll hunt it down and hopefully end up with a patch to submit but some guidance would be appreciated as I'm new to the doxygen code base.

Any help in how to build xapian for doxygen would also be appreciated.

Comment: printlex is one of the last additions to doxygen (for debugging purposes), it is defined in message.cpp / message.h. For building the doxygen.exe xapian is not necessary it is just required for searching indexing in separate executables. To generate doxygen you need python (2.7), flex and bison.

Comment: You can download prebuild xapian libraries for Windows from here: ftp://ftp.stack.nl/pub/users/dimitri/xapian_doxygen_win.zip

Comment: @albert I have Python 2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,3.0 and 3.4 installed on my machine... xapian... what a pain. 

So is there a correct way to deal with the build errors the printlex is causing or is what I did (delete the offending lines) the right thing to do?

Comment: @doxygen Thanks for the link! You should put that on the doxygen build page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was my version of Flex that was causing the problems.

I got it from the gnu32 project (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/flex.htm). It's a very old version 2.5.4a (1997). This was where the doxygen build guide recommended that I get it from.

Updated it using the Win Flex-Bison project (http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/files/latest/download) and it worked. Perhaps the windows build guide should be updated?

What is the minimum required versions of flex and bison to correctly build?

P.S. I can now build with xapian etc, but it throws a ton of warnings about vc90.pdb being missing, pehaps that should be added to the xapian_doxygen_win.zip file.

Comment: New build with an updated flex also resolved the bug I was trying to fix.